# Usage of binary search

Tags: c++, vector, task, binary-search

I am currently working on my homework and I am almost done, but I don't seem to quite understand the last part of my task. Here is the task description and the bold text is what I do not understand :

> Write a program that keeps an appointment book. Make a class Appointment that stores a description of the appointment, the appointment day, the starting time, and the ending time. Your program should keep the appointments in a sorted vector.Users can add appointments and print out all appointments for a given day. **When a new appointment is added, use binary search to find where it should be inserted in the vector. Do not add it if it conflicts with another appointment.**

I just learned about linear/binary search algorithms last week and now I am not able to see what I should exactly do here. With a binary search, I can locate a value inside a, for example, vector (as in my case), right? Then how can I determine where I should insert the newly added appointment in my vector? What should tell me where it should be inserted? I am also slightly confused that I have to use binary search to find where the appointment has to be inserted even though the vector might have no elements yet. It first says "when an appointment is added" and then it also says "..to find where it should be inserted", which conflicts with my solution a little since I push back newly added appointments to the vector, but the description asks me to first find where it should be added and then inserted. Sounds confusing, but I can't formulate it better right now.

I am not asking for direct code and this is why I haven't posted my solution so far. I just want some clarification as to what exactly I should do with that binary search. Thanks

Comment: Not only can you locate a specific value in the vector using binary search, you can also locate the place where a value would be *if it were already in there*. (Abandon your "solution" - you should not use `push_back`, so it's not a solution at all.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Okay, thanks. I was not sure about `push_back` either, so I probably have to use the `std::vector::insert` member function instead?

Comment: Yes, you should. See my answer for possible logic for this task.

Answer (score 1):

[Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) serves for searching sorted data with average complexity of `O(log n)`. In [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) you may explicit insert value at desired position (as long as it is valid) using [insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) method.

Now, about you task:

> When a new appointment is added, use binary search to find where it should be inserted in the vector. Do not add it if it conflicts with another appointment.

General approach would be:

```
struct Appointment
{
    Date date;
    Time begin;
    Time end;
    //other required members
};
```

Now, the book itself:

```
class AppointmentsBook
{
private:
    typedef std::vector<Appointment> ApVec;

    ApVec _appointments;

public:
    //constructors, finding methods etc.
    bool add(const Appointment& ap);
};

bool AppointmentsBook::add(const Appointment& ap)
{
    ApVec::iterator pos = this->find_insert_position(ap); //find_insert_position implements searching using binary search algo

    if((pos != this->_appointments.end()) && (ap->date == pos->date) && intersects(ap.begin, ap.end, pos->begin, pos->end))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        this->_appointments.insert(pos, ap);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is pseudo-code, of course. `intersects()` functions should check if two time scopes conflict with each other.

Note, that if you are allowed to use some features from `std` library, you can use [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), which uses binary search and requires elements to be partially ordered:

> The range [first, last) must be at least partially ordered, i.e. partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`.

---

Oh, one more thing: if you are wondering, why condition inside `add()` checks for:

```
`if(pos != this->_appointments.end())`
```

For empty book (and thus, empty `_appointments` vector), `find_insert_position()` should return `this->_appointments.end()`, signalling, that there is no appointments yet. Then, other checks can (and should!) be omitted and new appointment is inserted at the end of the vector.

---

Using `std::lower_bound`, your `find_insert_position()` function could look like this:

```
AppointmentsBook::ApVec::iterator AppointmentsBook::find_insert_position(const Appointment& ap)
{
    if(this->_appointments.empty())
        return this->_appointments.end();

    return std::lower_bound(this->_appointments.begin(), this->_appointments.end(), ap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am currently reading about `std::lower_bound`. I am allowed to make use of std librariy

Comment: @nenko182 I updated my answer for possible implementation using `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I implemented the `find_insert_position()`, using `std::lower::bound`, function, but I get an error saying "vect (in your case ApVec) does not name a type". I did the `typedef` declaration in the class private section. What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you put declaration of `find_insert_position()` inside your class? See the bottom of my answer,

Comment: Yes, of course I did. I have declared it. It only gives an error when I start to implement the function - it does not give an error inside the class.

Comment: My mistake, change `ApVec::iterator` to `AppointmentsBook::ApVec::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are permitted to make use of standard library algorithms, std::lower_bound performs a binary search and returns a position within the vector for the new element to be inserted. 
Before inserting, you can check that location (if it doesn't point to end()) to see if there's already an appointment at the same time.

Consult [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) for more information about lower_bound and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reorder the entry vector on every new appointment, so the vector index represents the appointment order. if a new appointment have a start time between other appointments start and end time, you have to keep the older appointment.

Algorithem:

1. binary search vor appointments before the new appiointment
2. check for collision
3. push new empty element in the vector
4. shift other appointments at index caluclatet in 2
5. insert new appointment at index calculatet in 2

Comment: `1. Check for collision`, `2. binary search vor appointments before the new appiointment` -> are you sure about this?